# Why there is a sound from speakers and earphones simultaneously at a time?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio

I have a earphone(fine) and a new laptop `dell inspiron-3501` with `ubuntu 22.04` with kernel `5.15.0-25-generic`. But I have a audio problem. Normally speakers works fine. But when I plugin earphone then the laptop does not recognize earphone. With alsamixer command if I increase the volume of headphone then sound in earphone works but speakers also plays simultaneously along with earphone. Also next time alsamixer always has volume 0 for headphones.

This is my alsamixer screenshot.

[image]

**EDIT:** Even if I plug in or not earphone the output will be the same as in below picture. Speakers are working fine though only earphones are not detected.

[image]

Comment: Your issue appears to be different that I thought to be.  I would recommend trying it on different computer.